# TensorFlow to PyTorch: x=tf.keras.layers.PReLU(shared_axes=[1,2])(x)

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

How to write this line on PyTorch?
tf.keras.layers.PReLU(shared_axes=[1,2])(x)

It is important to have shared_axes=[1,2]

I found this solution somewhere, but Imnot sure if it is correct:
nn.PReLU(num_parameters=1)

Thanks in advance everyone!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that PyTorch does the `shared_axis` operation as default. We can check with the following code:
TensorFlow:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.keras.layers.PReLU(shared_axes=(1,2))
x.build((None, 10, 10, 3))  # initialize the weights to an image-like input shape
print(x.weights[0].shape)  # will print 'TensorShape([1, 1, 3])'

# if we omit the shared_axes parameter we get:
x = tf.keras.layers.PReLU()
x.build((None, 10, 10, 3))  # initialize the weights to an image-like input shape
print(x.weights[0].shape)  # will print 'TensorShape([10, 10, 3])'
```

PyTorch:

```py
from torch import nn
x = nn.modules.activation.PReLU()
print(x.weight.shape)  # will print 'torch.Size([1])'

# to get one parameter per filter we have to set it
x = nn.modules.activation.PReLU(3)
print(x.weight.shape)  # will print 'torch.Size([3])'
```

Hope that helps to understand the differences. You can also initialize the torch version with a list to get the second version of the TF code.
One additional difference is that TensorFlow initializes with `0.0`, while PyTorch initializes with `0.25`. To get the exact same initialization as TensorFlow, do:

```py
f = #number of filters of the previous layer
x = nn.modules.activation.PReLU(f, init=0.0)
```